# SessionException occurs when crawling with solrCloud

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, manifoldcf

I using solrCloud 6.1.0. I trying to crawl with manifoldcf2.4. But it does not work.

The following is the execution environment.
java:1.8(However, it is 1.7 when installing manifoldcf)
zookeeper:3.4.9

If i start job with manifoldcf, I can crawl the first few items.
However, after a while, a connection error of zookeeper occurs, and a part of the node configured by solrCloud falls.

Below is the error log of zookeeper.

> ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter
>   null:org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /aliases.json at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
>   at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.getData(ZooKeeper.java:1151) at
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$7.execute(SolrZkClient.java:252)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient$7.execute(SolrZkClient.java:249)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkCmdExecutor.retryOperation(ZkCmdExecutor.java:65)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.SolrZkClient.getData(SolrZkClient.java:249)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader.updateAliases(ZkStateReader.java:556)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:296)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:169)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.ProxyUserFilter.doFilter(ProxyUserFilter.java:241)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter$2.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:140)
>   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.server.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:384)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SolrHadoopAuthenticationFilter.java:145)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.solr.servlet.HostnameFilter.doFilter(HostnameFilter.java:86)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter
>   null:org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = Session expired for /aliases.json at
>   org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:127)

I do not know why zookeeper gets cut off in the middle of crawling.

Someone, please teach.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is the session expiring as the error itself says:

> org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$SessionExpiredException:
>   KeeperErrorCode = **Session expired** for /aliases.json

This likely indicates that your client is pausing for long periods of 
time, maybe crawling a long document or getting data transferred over the net, enough for the session to expire.
You could try extending the timeout period as explained [here](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_advancedConfiguration), but there's a chance that it would just extend the crawl period a little bit without solving your issue. 
Please refer to the [zookeeper troubleshooting guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ZOOKEEPER/Troubleshooting) and/or [this interesting post](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/SessionExpiredException-help-please-td6825904.html) for a full resolution.